# Stop a key from firing an event in C# using ProcessCmdKey?

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

So I'm making a form, and I want the left and right keys to ONLY correspond to a numericUpDown box that I have on the form. So the code I wrote is the following :

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
         if (keyData == Keys.Right)
        {

            numericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(numericUpDown1.Value + 1);
        }
         if (keyData == Keys.Left)
        {
            try
            {
                numericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(numericUpDown1.Value - 1);
            }
            catch { }
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

However it seems to still do the default action of moving between different objects on the form if that's what the selected view is currently. How do I stop the default action?

Comment: did you try to "return true;" for the cases where you don't want processing to continue?

Comment: Your code won't even compile. You have no return statements in a method that should return a bool.

Comment: No I didn't return true...that seems to work the majority of the time (unless I press the keys very quickly)...It's not something that breaks the form though, so I'm okay with it if someone decides to do it occassionally. THANKS!

Comment: @user2678856 if returning true worked, can you please mark that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return true when you don't want the default action to be carried out.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
     if (keyData == Keys.Right)
    {

        numericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(numericUpDown1.Value + 1);
        return true;
    }
     if (keyData == Keys.Left)
    {
        try
        {
            numericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(numericUpDown1.Value - 1);
            return true;
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should return true to indicate you have processed the key stroke message so that no other controls get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
     if (keyData == Keys.Right){
        numericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(numericUpDown1.Value + 1);
        return true;
     }
     else if (keyData == Keys.Left){
        try {
            numericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(numericUpDown1.Value - 1);              
        }
        catch { }
        return true;
    }        
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

**NOTE:** It looks like that you didn't post the code you run? I **highly recommend** you to post the actual code of yours, your code doesn't even compile because lacking of `return`. And your code lacks the `return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);` which is required to process other keys.

Answer (score 0):

you can add an event hanlder and do this:

```
private void keypressed(Object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    {

        e.Handled = true; //this line will do the trick
        //add the rest of your code here. 

    }
}
```